# Extract lines from files with names begining with given letter

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Got here a list of columns, as follows:

```
59  LOUIS   1202    +1
60  FREDDIE 1201    +4
61  FINLAY  1200    -2
62  LEON    1137    +12
63  HARLEY  1132    +6
64  DAVID   1127    -1
65  MOHAMMAD1100    +6
66  REECE   1095    -1
67  KIAN    1090    0
68  KAI     1056    -6
69  KYLE    1030    -18
70  BRANDON 1011    -4
71  HAYDEN  1006    +5
72  ZACHARY 995     +10
73  KIERAN  973     -12
73  LUCA    973     -1
75  ASHTON  954     +4
76  BAILEY  939     -6
77  JAKE    913     +10
78  GABRIEL 910     +14
79  SAM     900     -2
80  EVAN    890     0
81  BRADLEY 847     -13
```

How could be extracted only the lines with, for example, letter "L", as follows:

```
73  LUCA    973     -1
```

Comment: Does the `L` need to be in the second column? How are columns defined (spaces? tabs?)? Can the `L` be anywhere in the column or does it have to be the first letter? Your question says only "with", but you seem to be expecting "starts with". Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Its to extract the lines which contains the name with given letter, for example: Need here lines which names starts with letter "E", then it should return a file that contains `80  EVAN    890     0` only, just as the guy down there just answered.

Comment: Just curious about the [sed] tag: does the solution have to use `sed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be duplicated, but anyway, if it was understood, one may do it as follows:

First, save the list in a some `nameslist.txt` file, then:

`sed -rn '/^[^\s]+\s+[F]/p' list.txt > result.txt`, which should return following output in `result.txt` file:

`60 FREDDIE   1201    +4
 61 FINLAY  1200    -2`

Answer (score 19):

```
awk '$2 ~ /^L/' file
```

Tells `awk` to test the second field `$2` using the regex `~` expression `^L` and print the matching lines.

The regex matches the second field (`$2`) when it starts `^` with `L`

Comment: `awk 'substr($2, 1, 1) == "L"' file` would also work

Comment: @glennjackman Are there any benifits to using `substr` over a regex field match as in this answer?

Comment: Don't know. There may be a new microseconds performance benefit, but there may not be. I was just pointing out an alternate function.

Answer (score 7):

Building on @bu5hman's answer: With awk, you can easily pass the letter as a parameter:

```sh
awk -v letter="L" 'substr($2, 1, 1) == letter' file
# or with a constructed regex
awk -v letter="L" '$2 ~ "^" letter' file
```

Comment: +1.  The `$2 ~ ...` version also allows regexp searches like `-v letter='[FL]'` to match lines where the name begins with either an F or an L.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have that list in `list.txt`, you can do the following:

```
 grep -h L list.txt > list_L.txt
```

Explanation: `grep L list.txt` gives you all the lines containing an uppercase L. The option `-h` suppresses the output of the file name, but is only necessary if you are searching through multiple files (e.g. `grep -h L lis*.txt`). Adding `> list_L.txt` redirects the lines to the specified file.

If the L must only occur at the beginning of a "word" (on name, in this case), you need to tweak the above command a bit:

```
 grep -h '\<L' list.txt > list_L.txt
```

Adding `\<` matches the beginning of a "word", so `\<L` selects lines containing a word beginning with an uppercase L.

Answer (score 2):

Another grep example:

```
grep -E "[0-9]+ +L" file
```

+ matches one or more occurrence of the previous character, so in this case we match at least one numeric character, and at least one space, followed by a capital L.

-E is required to interpret the + as a special character instead of a literal '+'

output:

```
59  LOUIS   1202    +1
62  LEON    1137    +12
73  LUCA    973     -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid RegEx when possible. AWK example:

```
index($2, "L") == 1
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea to answer with a working example like `awk 'index($2, "L") == 1' file` like everybody else does?

Comment: @Freddy I posted my code carefully and purposefully. Your code is a valid shell script, while mine is a valid AWK script. Please stop changing it.

Comment: I stopped changing it, I'm just curious. This question is tagged with `sed` and not everybody knows how to run your script, that's all.

Comment: @Freddy its public information for at least 20 years now... https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/awk.html

Comment: This is about as useful as answering with just `oldfile newfile` without bothering to mention `cp`, when someone asks "how do i copy a file?"  and then snarkily pointing out that cp has been public information for decades.    Actually, it's worse than that because "avoid regex when possible" is a terrible answer for a simple text processing problem.